# Местонахождение исполняемого файла php в dockere

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

Такая небольшая проблема есть. Раньше я ставил php вручную и в ide vs code я ставил плагин автодополнения кода "php intellisense". В настройках этого плагина была строчка, которая указывала на исполняемый файл php, чтобы плагин мог корректно работать. Сейчас я работаю в одной компании и разворачивал их проект с Dockerа. Там уже вшита php версия и я не могу найти исполняемый файл php, так как вручную я его не ставил, а он установился при разворачивании проекта куда то (раньше будь на ubuntu был /urs/bin/php7.4). Сейчас по данному пути php нет, соответственно вписать я не могу исполняемый файл в настройки плагина
Как быть?

Comment: whereis php не помог?

Comment: нет, не сработало

Comment: ну если в докере , очевидно что php находится в каком то из контейнеров и вы так же очевидно не сможете прописать путь к php локально.  Почти наверняка в ide есть возможность работать с докером и  контейнерами, возможность указывать что php в данном случае живет в одном из них явно быть должна предусмотрена.